# OneSignal using CocoaPods dependency manager breaks PhoneGapBuild

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, phonegap, onesignal

Since OneSignal started using CocoaPods I've been unable to do an iOS build on PGB.
PGB has CocoaPods support, so theoretically it should still work.

I'm receiving the following error:

```
"plugman-151 install --platform ios --project /project --plugin onesignal-cordova-plugin@^2.4.6 --nohooks=.": Fetching plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin@^2.4.6" via npm
Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" at "2.4.6" for ios
Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12)
pod: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I'm wondering if there is anyone successfully building with OneSignal on iOS in PGB that might have some insight and a solution. (My Android build is fine).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
Specifying the plugin as version 2.4.5 solves the build issue:

```
<gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="2.4.5" source="npm" />
```

More accurately, it circumvents the issue because they didn't use CocoaPods in that version.

The problem is that you don't get access to the latest functionality - in my case specifically external user ids (setExternalUserId)